# Java Applet Embed Issues

Tags: java, html, eclipse, nullpointerexception, applet

I've been stuck with this for ages now, and none of the content I could find on the web has been much use. I've built a Java Applet that works 100% with no errors in Eclipse's Applet Viewer. I've exported it as a jar and allowed the web address through as an Exception Site in Java Config.

When I embed the applet in HTML though, it doesn't work, a NullPointerException every time, and the Java Console shows nothing.

My embed code:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" width="800" height="600">
    <param name="codebase" value="." />
    <param name="code" value="appletpackage.Main" />
    <param name="archive" value="Applet.jar" />
    <param name="scriptable" value="true" />
    <param name="mayscript" value="true" />
</object>
```

My Applet `init()`:

```
public void init() {
    setSize(800, 600);
    obstGen = new ObstacleGenerator(100, getWidth(), getHeight() - 256);
    setBackground(new Color(112, 199, 255));
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    try {
        base = getDocumentBase();
        character = getImage(base, "data/putinstill.png");
        background = getImage(base, "data/putinbg.png");
        towers = getImage(base, "data/towerbg.png");
        putindown = getImage(base, "data/putindown.png");
        exclaim = getImage(base, "data/exclaim.png");
        obst1 = getImage(base, "data/obst1.png");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Anyone got ideas?

Comment: Which is it, a `NullPointerException` or nothing on the console?

Comment: Both... when I click "Error. Click for details" I get a `NullPointerException` dialog but when I click "Details" on that dialog it shows an empty Java Console

Comment: 1) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`  2) `setSize(800, 600);`  An applet size should be set in HTML.  Don't do that. 3) *"My embed code:"*  The best way to deploy a JWS app. or applet is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).